# recursive file list with md5 in R

Tags: r

I am trying to create a simple csv table output in R that contains a listing of only files through a directory (recursively).  The output should contain, at minimum 3 columns:

- The Full Path (e.g. \path\to\file\somefile.txt)
- File size
- MD5 Hash of file
- (additional file.info properties (data created, modified etc.) would be helpful, but not strictly necessary

I have the following script that I hacked together from various places on the internet, which works, but I think is not the 'best' way to do it and/or might be brittle.  I am seeking any comments/suggests on how to clean this up and help improve my R-skills.  Thanks!

*I am particularly concerned about how cbind works, and how does it "know" if row arrangement/order is preserved?

```
    library(digest)
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

test_dir <- "C:\\Path\\To\\Folder"
outfile <- "out.csv"

file.names <- list.files(test_dir, recursive = TRUE, full.names = TRUE)

md5s <- sapply(file.names, digest, file = TRUE, algo = "md5")

q <- map(file.names, file.info)

file.sizes <- map_df(q, extract, c("size"))

output <- cbind(file.names, file.sizes, md5s)

write_csv(output, str_c("./R/", outfile))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One tip might be to use the `openssl` md5 function instead of `digest`.

```
library(openssl)

md5s <- md5(file.names)
```

It's already vectorised so you won't need to use sapply which may improve your processing speed (depending on how big a file you want to hash).

In terms of **cbind**, it will keep the order of the first column you are binding to using your key (md5) so the output will have the order that file.names has.

Comment: Thanks Derwin, using openssl definitely was much faster, however now my cbind doesn't work.  The class of the md5() return is "hash" "md5", and when I try to cbind, I get error :  Error in as.data.frame.default(x[[i]], optional = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = stringsAsFactors) : 
  cannot coerce class ‘c("hash", "md5")’ to a data.frame.  I tried to do as.character(md5s) but that also results in a similar error

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out just using:  t <- map_chr(md5s, as.character)
works great, thanks Derwin.  marking this as answered.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Answer (score 2):

The chosen answer did not give me the md5 of the actual file but of the file's names! I got the real md5 (which matched the md5 generated from other sources) using the following command. This seems to work with only one file at a time.

`library(openssl)`

`md5 <- as.character(md5(file(file.name, open="rb")))`

For multiple files the following command worked for me

`library(tools)`

`md5 = as.vector(md5sum(file.names))`